# Multiple strings in one variable js

Tags: javascript, variables

So i was making some console stuff for my things and i wanted to make some kind of"detection" of command, like if what i input into the thing is command then make it change color of text to white

it did work if i use variable like this

```
var commands = ['command1'];
```

or

```
var commands = 'command1';
```

but i did not with variable used like in code down there

code:

```
var commands = ['command1', 'commands2']

window.setInterval(function() {
    if (input.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == !commands) {
        console.log("test")
    }
}, 32);
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML along with it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code at the bottom? Right now, you are checking if the string in the `innerHTML` is `false` since `!` an array is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using `indexOf`. `indexOf()` returns -1 when the supplied value isn't present

```js
var commands = ['command1', 'commands2']
commands.indexOf(input.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById("cmd");
var output = document.getElementById("demo"); 

var commands = ['command1', 'commands2'];

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
    var result = null;

    // indexOf() returns -1 when the supplied value isn't present
    if(commands.indexOf(cmd.value.toLowerCase()) > -1){
      // your logic to change color, or do whatever
      result =  "yes";
    } else {
      result = "no";
    }
    output.textContent = result;

});
```

```html
<input id="cmd">

<p id="demo"></p>
```